# Multi-threading safety for python string operation via '%'

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading

I have two threading to invoke below function:

```
template = 'My name is %s'

def sayhi(name):
    global template
    print template % name
```

thread A will invoke as below:

```
sayhi('Tom')
```

thread B will invoke as below:

```
sayhi('Jerry')
```

My question is whether it is safety for global var 'template'.

Very thanks!

Comment: Does `template` ever change?

Comment: @NPE global var 'template' will not change in running time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `template` never changes, the code is perfectly fine and will work as expected.

(If `template` were subject to change, this would complicate things somewhat and the answer would be "it depends on what you're expecting".)

Comment: In fact, since `template` never changes, there's no need for the `global` declaration at all.

Answer (score 2):

I think your concern is that `template` is in critical section. In a more complicated case, if value of `template` will be changed, then you have to use a lock before change. Like this, in both of you threads:

```
.....
mylock = threading.RLock()

mylock.acquire()
# do something to template
mylock.release()
....
```